# How to skip blank spaces in Flex?

Tags: regex, whitespace, flex-lexer

I'm using flex to generate my lexical analyzer for a college homework. It should recognize integers, floats, variables names and math operators. It also should ignore any blank like chars, like " ","\n","\t" and so on. To start, I'm only try to catch whitespace chars like this " " or more whitespace chars concatenated. My rule file is this:

```
%{
  #include<stdio.h>
%}
%%
[0-9]+ printf("inteiro:%s\n",yytext);
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ printf("fracionário:%s\n",yytext);
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-z0-9]* printf("variável:%s\n",yytext);
\+|\-|\*|\/|\*\* printf("operador:%s\n",yytext);
\(|\) printf("parênteses:%s\n",yytext);
[[:space:]]|[[:space:]]+;
%%
```

with the following input

`12  +            413`

it generates this output:

`inteiro:12
operador:+
inteiro:413`

I would like to how why the last line couldn't be something like:

`[[:space:]]+;`

Comment: It didn't work. I would like to know why

Comment: @GabrielRado: Your code works as expected, ¿no? I think you are asking why the last rule couldn't be shorter, but that is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule

```
    [[:space:]]|[[:space:]]+;
```

is a bit odd.

A flex rule consists of a pattern and an (optional) action, *separated by whitespace*. Since there is no space before the `;`, it is part of the pattern, not the action. So that pattern matches either a single whitespace character (`[[:space:]]`) or (`|`) a sequence of one or more whitespace characters followed by a semicolon (`[[:space:]]+;`).

Since there is no action in that rule, the pattern is just ignored. (That's a flex extension. Lex requires that an action be present, even if it does nothing.) In effect, that means that you will ignore all whitespace (one character at a time) and you will also ignore semicolons if they are preceded by whitespace.

What you probably intended was

```
    [[:space:]]+     /* sem ação */
```

(It is useful to insert a comment to make the absence of action visible.)

---

By the way, character classes are usually much more readable than a forest of leaning timber (that is, a bunch of backslash escapes). Also, flex lets you use double quotes to quote strings.

So instead of

```
    \+|\-|\*|\/|\*\*    /* operador */
    \(|\)               /* parênteses */
```

you could write:

```
    [-+*/]|"**"         /* operador */
    [()]                /* parênteses */
```

In the first character class, it is important to put the <kbd>-</kbd> either at the beginning or the end of the list of characters so that it is not interpreted as defining a range of characters.

And, instead of inserting your own debugging printf statements, consider using the `-d` (debug) option when building your scanner. That will print out complete debugging information for you, letting you see precisely what is being done by the scanner.